# Why I cannot access Facebook login SDK even though my connection is on HTTPS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have two instances running behind an AWS ALB. All traffic whether HTTP or HTTPS is routed to HTTPS at the load balancer level. I am using amazon certificate for HTTPS connection. I am trying to sign up users using the facebook login SDK. According to facebook that all traffic should be happening on HTTPS. Even though my connection is secure facebook is complaining that it is not secure.

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see all my connections are secure and my certificate is valid, however facebook is still complaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake. My callback url was http instead of https.